# Cannot get FreeType library to work in Mac OS X Mountain Lion

Tags: xcode, macos, linker, linker-errors, freetype

I have an OpenGL project which works/compiles fine in Windows.
I wanted to port the application to Mac OS.
I got the application up and running on Mac, but the text inside the project is not visible.
 So I decided to use a 3rd party library for text rendering in Mac, I came across FreeType, which has many advantages such as anti-aliasing and UNICODE support.

So, I downloaded the library on my Mac, './configure'd it, did 'make' and 'make install' as I would normally do. 

Then in Xcode I set search paths for both include and library directories,

 **/usr/local/include** and **/usr/local/lib** respectively. 
Then I added 'other linker flags' in Xcode, **freetype-configure --libs** gave me following flags- 
 -**L/usr/local/lib  -lfreetype -lz -lbz2**, I added them in Xcode.

Now, whenever I include a freetype header there is no problem, but when I call any method from the freetype library, it gives me following linker error.

[image: Linker Errors By Xcode]

After looking up on google I found out that I have to set the build targets accordingly, I did that, now my application builds for **i386 x86** the issue still persist.

I also tried following flags while configuring freetype ./**configure CC="gcc -arch i386" CXX="g++ -arch i386"**
which did not help either.

I am relatively new to Mac OS X/Unix environment, I have previously got freetype working on windows with VS 2008. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

### What:

It seems you have more than one libfreetype.dylib file in your library search paths.

**/master_repository/......../lib**     contains one and **/usr/local/lib**                      contains another

**-lfreetype** is a convenient way of telling the linker to look for file named libfreetype.dylib in all the directories specified with **-L** flags. Because -L/master_repository... comes before -L/usr/local/lib in the linker argument list, the linker uses the first instance it finds and attempts linking to that one.

### Fix:

- Reorganising  your **-L** flags so that **-L/usr/local/lib** comes before the other. Avoid this option if you can.
- Removing the extra search path, leaving only the relevant one.
- Specifying the library explicitly instead of relying on the convenient **-l** by replacing **-lfreetype** with a full path to a library: **/usr/local/lib/libfreetype.dylib**